# npx install within vscode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npx

react-app my-app not working
i have tried both D:\ and Users<name> folders to run this command but gives me this error stack:

```
PS C:\Users\<myusername>\node_modules\npx> npx create-react-app my-app
node:fs:1349
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'my-app'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1349:3)
    at Object.module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\<my user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:23:13)
    at createApp (C:\Users\<my user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:257:6)
    at C:\Users\<my user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:223:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'my-app'
}
```

reading on github post i tried to make a folder from windows into user directory and ran the npx command from there but no use.. please advise.. thanks..

Comment: Are you running as a non administrator account? That message means your account doesn't have write permissions in the directory you are working in.

Comment: Why are you in the `node_modules/npx` directory?